# Delete alphanumeric rows SQL

Tags: sql

So in my database I have location codes i.e

```
0101A
0102A
```

And they go upto 37X so my last location is 0137X

In my physical warehouse 0101A is the bottom left and 0137X is the top right (there are more aisles but just working on 01 for now)

It's a single text column, which is made up of

```
aisle(02) bay(02) level(01).
```

If for example I wanted to delete all locations on level X how would I go about formulating the statement?

I ran it and it deleted every single location from 0101A to 0137X even though I stipulated the started location was 0503X.

I have been told

"There is no way to consider the the separate parts of the location (aisle, bay, level) in the delete process."

Comment: Please always tag your SQL requests with the DBMS you are using in order to only get answers that work for you.

Comment: "I ran it and it deleted every single location from 0101A to 0137X even though I stipulated the started location was 0503X": Show us your delete statement, then we can explain what semantic mistake leads to deleting all rows.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bad idea to store multiple information (aisle, bay, level) in one column.

It is, however, not difficult in your case to find the locations of one aisle, one bay or one level, because the format is fixed (two digits for the aisle, two for the bay, one letter for the level). Use

- `WHERE location LIKE '01___'` for aisle 01
- `WHERE location LIKE '__01_'` for bay 01
- `WHERE location LIKE '____X'` for level X.

This can of course be combined:

- `WHERE location LIKE '01__X'` for aisle 01, level X